# divide by zero encountered in double_scalars for derivative calculations

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I am learning to use python for numerical computations. I want to calculate derivative using the central difference method. When I try to set my interval dx, python takes it to 0 even though the actual value is (1/6)? Any way to get rid of this?

Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = 0
b = 1
n = 7
dx = np.float(((b-a)/n))
x = np.linspace(a,b,n)
xpp = np.zeros(n)

for ii in range(1,n-1):
    xpp[ii] = (x[ii-1] - 2*x[ii+1] + x[ii+1])/(pow(dx,2))
print xpp
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python 2.7, integer division does `floor`:

```
>>> a = 0
>>> b = 1
>>> n = 7
>>> (b - a) / n
0
```

=> `dx` become `0.0` => Inside `for` loop body, it is used as a dividor. (0<sup>2</sup> = 0)

You need to convert one (or both) of operand to float to prevent floor-division:

```
>>> float(b - a) / n
0.14285714285714285
```

Comment: Cool! Thanks mate! Solved my problem :)

Answer (score 1):

you can also import below **future** to avoid floor division.

```
from __future__ import division
```